# Django UniqueConstraint doesn't works with ManyToManyField, got exception FieldDoesNotExist

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

The migration stopped working when switching from `ForeignKey` between `Shop` and `user` to a `ManyToManyField`. I wanted shops to be able to be owned by different users at the same time:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=120)
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   ##before
    shopuser= models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="shopusers", blank=True)    ##after

    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['shopuser', 'name'], name='user cant have the same shop twice!')] 
    
    ## after:
    @property
    def get_shopuser(self):
        return ", ".join([u.username for u in self.shopuser.all()])

class Warehouse(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField('address', max_length=120)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="User", blank=True)
```

> django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: NewShop has no field named 'shopusers'

I thought by choosing a related name I can use multiple relations to the `User` model? I already tried **completely deleting my database (and migrations folder)** and migrate from start, but tht did not help :(

Example where I would call the code:

admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Shop)
class ShopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "related_shopuser")
    list_filter = ("name", "shopuser")
    fieldsets = [("Requrired Information", {"description": "These fields are required", 
                                            "fields": (("name", "shopuser"))}),]

    def related_shopuser(self, obj):
        return obj.get_shopuser
```

Where does Djanog migrations get the `NewShop` from `FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))`? Is it automatically generated from the ModelName `Shop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue

The **`UniqueConstraint`** on **`ManyToManyField`** will not work as expected. If you want to ***enforce*** the constraint, you should define a ***intermediate model*** and connect them using the [**`through`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) parameter.

For the sake of simplicity, I assume you have a model as below,

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=120)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=[
                    'user',
                    'name'
                ],
                name='user cant have the same shop twice!'
            )
        ]
```

and now you want make the **`user`** field to a **`ManyToManyField`** from `ForeignKey`

**Note:** I have changed the field name to `users` from `user`, which is more approriate.

### Method-1 : Remove unique constraint

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=120)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Now, run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands

### Method-2: use an intermediate model

```
class ShopUserIntermediateModel(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey('Shop', models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=[
                    'shop',
                    'user'
                ],
                name='user cant have the same shop twice!'
            )
        ]


class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=120)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=ShopUserIntermediateModel)
```

Answer (score -1):

If not required (the project is already in production), try deleting your migration files, or at least the migration where the user field was added in the first time

Comment: benn there, done that, as stated in my last sentence.

Comment: But did you delete your migrations files?, Not only the database, because when you do this, all of the previous model historical migrations are deleted as well and you don't have any problems with new fields or changes

Comment: yes, I deleted the `migrations` folder and the database.

Comment: I added some code from the admin.py. Can this error be realted to some errors in my code besides the models,py?

Comment: That error is most commonly related to migrations and changes in the fields, I really think that you dont delete all the migrations related to this model. I have the same problem today in one of my projects, because I change a `FKField` to a `M2MField` like you and the only way I found was deleting the migrations of the module. On the other hand, you will need to get into the migrations and specify what to do with that field in the new database.

Comment: I deleted the `migrations` folder and the `.sqlite3` file - what else could I try?